# How to play animation in order in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have two animations for two layers, layer1 and layer2, each has different path. So, I want to know how can play them in order. first play layer1's animation, and then layer2.

here is my two animation code!

**layer1**

```
    CALayer *layer1 = [CALayer layer];
    [self.layer addSublayer:layer1];
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation1 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    layer1.contents = (id)image1.CGImage;
    layer1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    layer1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image1.size.width, image1.size.height);
    animation1.path = path1;
    animation1.duration = 2.0f;
    animation1.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
    [layer1 addAnimation:animation1 forKey:@"position"];
```

**layer2**

```
    CALayer *layer2 = [CALayer layer];
    [self.layer addSublayer:layer2];
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation2 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    layer2.contents = (id)image2.CGImage;
    layer2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    layer2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image2.size.width, image2.size.height);
    animation2.path = path2;
    animation2.duration = 2.0f;
    animation2.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
    [layer2 addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"position"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a delegate for the first animation and start the second animation in the `animationDidStop:finished:` delegate method.